# c++ vcl TListView Column Header not drawn at onShow

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe2, tlistview

**Intro**: I want to use a TListView for displaying a table. For editing purposes I made a subclass of vcl's TListview, but didn't change much beside clicking on cells. More importantly, I didn't change any draw events for the TListView class.

**The Problem**: When I open the form, the table's header get only drawn... half:
[image]

After clicking into the header, minimizing the window or opening a different dialog first, the header appears again:
[image]

**Attempts**: I tried calling `Update()`, `Redraw()` and `Invalidate()` on FormShow, but nothing seems to change. I also set `DoubleBuffered=true` for the ListView. I also tried setting fixed widths as well as autosize (`width=-1` and -2)

**Question**: Is there a way to force especially the columns to get drawn? What did I do wrong so they would behave like this?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use a standard `TListView` instead of your subclassed component? If not, then what exactly DOES your subclass do/change?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your advice. standard ones were drawn in a normal way, and other instances of my class also were drawn correctly in other windows. I fixed the problem for now: the first column is used for checkboxes. Setting `this->Columns->Items[0]->Width=-1;` instead of a px-value like 20 was solving this problem.